# What should I choose - "kind of" or "kind of a"?

Tags: articles

There are some grammar tests in a book, Word Power Made Easy, one of which included this question:

> 'What (kind of, kind of a) car are you looking for?' asked the salesman.

Although I'd have personally preferred "kind of" over "kind of a", I do not see anything wrong in using the latter. Also the answer in the key was the" kind of" version. So, I want to ask why the "kind of" version is certainly correct.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation given in some grammar manuals (like Collins COBUILD English Guides, 1991) is that *count* nouns can be converted to *uncount* nouns when they are preceded by expressions like 'a kind of', 'a sort of', even 'a piece of'. These expressions are followed by a noun with **no** article.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. When a customer approaches a salesman, they asks what variety of car are they looking for. So "What kind of a car" literally in sense gives us a meaning, varieties in *one* car, this is not apt. It should be "what kind of car", which means 'varieties of car available in the showroom'.